# nodata leads to high pixel values after aggregation

Tags: qgis, nodata, aggregate, binary

I am working in QGIS with binary raster images and my task is to decrease the resolution from 0,1 to 5m.

Problem is, I have several areas that were excluded with “no-data” beforehand. After aggregation (r.resamp.stats -avg) some pixels have very high values. They got aggregated, although most of the area around was excluded with “no-data”.

For example, in the screenshot:
Greens = result from the aggregation of the reds. The upper half is alright, but the lower half has too high values as the contributing pixels are on a very small area.

[image]

I would like to exclude aggregated pixels if the no-data area is e.g. >=75%. My only idea so far is to look at all cases individually and to mask pixels that clearly misrepresent the actual situation. This seems to be very time consuming, is there any other way to handle this?